# Yii ClientScript

Tags: yii, clientscript

I would like to know is there a way to check if a coreScript is already registered?

for example the yiiactiveform

`Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('yiiactiveform');`

how to check if this corescript is already registered?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to know this? The framework is smart enough to not register the same script twice.

It seems to me that you can use

```
if(Yii::app()->clientScript->getPackageBaseUrl('yiiactiveform') === false) {
  // core script 'yiiactiveform' has not been registered yet
}
```

or extend CClientScript and implement a function to answer this, but that might be overkill.

Comment: because Im using a jquery ajax and upon loading the url,  Im removing the corescripts because if I dont.. it will duplicate. so I need to check if the corescript is already registered Im removed it using
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap();

Thanks for your answer it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing in page stuff, loading content, you'd probably (depending on your case) be better off using renderPartial() rather than render, this won't render the head and therefore include any registered core scripts. Is that an option?

Comment: yes Im using a renderPartial because im loading content via ajaxrequest and in the renderPartial, I processOutput = true so the jquery inside the renderPartial will return but if the current page already have the jquery produced in the renderPartial.. it will still generate the code so forexample I have an ajaxLink with the event alert().. it will alert twice.

Comment: Was the ajax query not made with jQuery? Is it not safe to assume that if you made an Ajax request then you have jQuery loaded already? So don't load it if Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest

Comment: On my init function in Controller I already declared the coreScript **jquery.js** and then on my ajaxRequest to move to another page I used renderPartial w/ ProcessOutput True and w/ this set to true, the jquery.js is also called coz there are jqueryscripts inside that renderPartial, so to avoid that I used this code `(Yii::app()->clientScript->getPackageBaseUrl('jquery') === false)` to check if coreScript is already there. but still im having w/ problems w/ some corescript that are registered after the renderPartial like **yiiactiveform** it always return false wether its already used or not